# Best way to make the async calls in angular 6 rxjs streams

Tags: rxjs, angular6

Consider the scenario of calling 4 different  **http** get calls to get 4 different counts from database. 
**What is the best logic to write the code** currently i wrote it like below

```
getfirstCount()
{
     this.http.post('ulr1',request,{headers:headers})
      .subscribe(response => {
          dataCount1 = response.count
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        },
        () => {
          this.getSecondCount();
        }
      )
}
```

How to implement the above scenario using **rxjs streams**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute all 4 calls at the same time using forkJoin:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

The statement below will receive a result when all of the 4 calls completed without errors. If you want to get a partial result when one of them fails, you need to use catchError on each separate http call.

```
    forkJoin(
        this.httpClient.get('uri_1'),
        this.httpClient.get('uri_2'),
        this.httpClient.get('uri_3'),
        this.httpClient.get('uri_4')
    ).pipe(catchError(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })).subscribe((joined: [Object, Object, Object, Object]) => {
        // handle array of results
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If your calls have to be made one after an other, you can chain your calls using a `flatMap`:

```ts
getfirstCount() {
 return this.http.post('ulr1',request,{headers:headers}) // <-- you have to returne an observable
  .subscribe(response => {
      dataCount1 = response.count
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
      this.getSecondCount();
    }
  )
}
```

And use it this way:

```ts
getfirstCount()
  .flatMap((dataFirstCount) => getSecondCount(dataFirstCount))
  .flatMap(...)
  .subscribe(/* handle dataFourthCount */)
```

Comment: I am afraid this does not work. `getfirstMap` returns a Subscription, since you subscribe within that function. Therefore you can not use `flatMap` on its return. Then, if you want a sequential execution, you better use `concatMap` rather than `flatMap`.